# Loads SDK into react-native app

Tags: react-native

Suppose I have **SDK** for a an application like true caller : https://github.com/truecaller/android-sdk . 
and I want to load that SDK on my own react-native app on both platforms android and iOS , I'm new to react-native and I searched the documentation and didn't find any clear tutorial.
Could you suggest a clear tutorial to get start with ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to understand how to build a react-native app over your existing java based app. This will give you better understanding of how to integrate your existing dependencies with react-native. Then following you can try to integrate any other java sdk compatible with react-native. Read this [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html).

**Update** - Here's another [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) which can help you build your own native modules.

Comment: I must first build an android app , then try to integrate react-native with it , then I will load the SDK to that app, Is it right ?